# HttpWebRequest: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, paypal, httpwebrequest

I'm making a asp.net web forms application which offers to pay using paypal. The application is supposed to make use of ssl. When i run my application all goes well until i select my button pay by paypal. When i press this button the following error occurs:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:
>   Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 203: Line 204:        //Retrieve the Response returned from the
>   NVP API call to PayPal. Line 205:        HttpWebResponse objResponse =
>   (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse(); Line 206:        string
>   result; Line 207:        using (StreamReader sr = new
>   StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
>
> Source File: C:\Users\willem\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WingtipToys\WingtipToys\Logic\PayPalFunctions.cs
>   Line: 205

Below my method in which the error ocurs

```
public string HttpCall(string NvpRequest)
{
    string url = pEndPointURL;

    string strPost = NvpRequest + "&" + buildCredentialsNVPString();
    strPost = strPost + "&BUTTONSOURCE=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(BNCode);

    HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    objRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
    objRequest.Method = "POST";
    //objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;

    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            myWriter.Write(strPost);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // No logging for this tutorial.
    }

    //Retrieve the Response returned from the NVP API call to PayPal.
    HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
    string result;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the SSL certificate required to invoke the endpoint?

Comment: I believe i did when windows asked me: Would you like to trust the IIS Express SSL certificate and continue? and then: Do you want to install this certificate? both i answered yes.

Comment: What I'm referring to is the endpoint you're attempting to create a web request for. When you browse that service endpoint using a browser, does it present you with a certificate that you have already installed/trusted locally on your workstation or not?

Comment: when i copy the url to my brower i get the following message: ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error                                                   Is this an answer to your questin? I have never used ssl before so i'm sorry if i'm not clear

Comment: Your code snippet does not specify the security protocol to use from what I can tell - example: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; There is a related topic here that I think you also need to look at [problems-with-paypal-api-http-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968997/problems-with-paypal-api-http-call)

Comment: Yes thank you, i don't get the error after specifying tls12.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code snippet does not specify the security protocol to use from what I can tell -

Example:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I found this after looking at different authentication methods against the paypal api.

There is a related topic here that deserves the credit. [problems-with-paypal-api-http-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968997/problems-with-paypal-api-http-call)

**Note:** This answer was added after the string of comments on the original OP question.